# Multi level sorting for a column cell in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, columnsorting

I am having a table column which contains a number of series(comma separated multiple values), in which i can apply sorting till first number(column name - Test_Values) but unable to continue sorting for the next numbers.

the actual tables are:

```
ID  Test
1   Test1
2   Test2
3   Test3
4   Test4
5   Test5
```

AND

```
new_ID  Test_ID T_Values
   1      1      2
   2      1      5
   3      1      9
   4      2      3
   5      2      4
   6      2      7  
   7      3      3
   8      3      4
   9      3      6
  10      4      4
  11      4      11
  12      4      9
  13      5      4  
  14      5      5
  15      5      9
```

Currently my table looks like :

```
 ID   Test   Test_Values
 1    Test1  2,5,9
 2    Test2  3,4,7
 3    Test3  3,4,6
 4    Test4  4,11,9
 5    Test5  4,5,9
```

and required output is

```
 ID  Test    Test_Values
 1   Test1   2,5,9
 3   Test3   3,4,6
 2   Test2   3,4,7
 5   Test5   4,5,9
 4   Test4   4,11,9
```

using this the below i can achieve sorting till first number:

```
cast(substring(Test_Values,1,CHARINDEX(',',Test_Values)-1) as integer)
```

can anyone suggest, thanks in advance

Comment: Fix yuor design, stop storing delimited data in your RDBMS, and don't store numerical data as a `varchar`. Also, what did you try. I suggest looking at the `ORDER BY` clause, however, as `Test Values` is a `varchar`, your ordering will likely not work as you expect. `'11,13,15'` has a **lower** value than `'2,3,4'`.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, it is a virtual column using to get values from multiple rows,

Comment: What do you mean a "virtual column"? If your data isn't really delimited, then show us what your actual data looks like, not the data from your failed attempt, and include the **full** SQL that created the failed attempt.

Comment: What is your SQL Serve version and what are the possible values for each number in the series?

Comment: @Larnu, i have edited my question, please check the actual values.

Comment: @Zhorov the SQL server version is v17.9.

Comment: @vasdevchandrakar No, it's the SQL Server Management Studio (a client tool) version. What dows `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: @Zhorov, it is SQL SERVER 2017